# How to perform text matching in text file and then move that next line after text into csv file?

Tags: c#, csv, text

I need to read the text file and then check the input text in contents in text file.

If input text exists then move nextline(after input text) into csv file.

**Sample Input:** input.txt

```
Hi

Hello

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Code Name       ID Customers     CID  Time.    %   
==================== ========= =========== ============ ===== ================= 

Harish SM        1001    Tower      India      44.58  
Siva DM          2310    Cata       China      56.78  



No Name           ID       Customers        
==================== ========= =========== 
MS Norway         1001     UNIBIC   

Datas are inside the csv file.
THanks
```

If I give input  "Code Name" then those 2 rows behind the CodeName will be saved in csv file upto newline.

If give input "No Name" then one row after No Name will be stored in another csv file.

Need to write code in c# only.

I'm little bit knowledge about c# console application

How can I write code to perform text file read and content into csv?.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Do you want to read data from text file and lookup more information from CSV based on codename? What do you mean by 2 rows behind?

Comment: There is two rows start with "Harish SM& Siva DM" below "Code Name" move it into csv file

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I just tried code but I don't know how to read next line of the matched "Code Name" using logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the format of the input file isn't the nicest setup, we need to do a read ahead in order to get it to work. The following procedure should work to extract the lines after the given ID code into an array of strings, the first containing the identifier line.

```
public string[] GetDataLinesFromFile(string filename, string searchString)
    {
        List<string> dataEntries = new List<string>();

        using (System.IO.StreamReader stream = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename))
        {
            System.IO.TextReader tr = stream;

            bool foundSearchString = false;
            string lastLine = string.Empty;
            string line = string.Empty;

            while (!stream.EndOfStream)
            {
                lastLine = line;
                line = tr.ReadLine();
                if (lastLine.Trim().StartsWith(searchString) && line.Contains("===================="))
                {
                    foundSearchString = true;
                    continue;
                }
                if (foundSearchString)
                {
                    // Start after the divider line
                    if (lastLine.Contains("===================="))
                        continue;

                    // If the current line read is a marker line, then our last line is actually a new identifier line
                    if (line.Contains("===================="))
                    {
                        // Can be used to look for multiple listings with the same ID
                        foundSearchString = false;
                        continue;

                        // If you only want the first found ID, uncomment this and comment out above
                        // return dataEntries.ToArray();
                    }

                    // If our previously read line is not empty, add it to the list of strings
                    if (lastLine.Trim().Length != 0)
                        dataEntries.Add(lastLine);
                }
            }
        }
        return dataEntries.ToArray();

    }
```

Then to use this function, just call it like so:

```
string[] entries = GetDataLinesFromFile("input.txt", "Code Name");
```

To save these to a .csv file, you would just iterate through each of the strings in the string array and look for the tab marker as a divider or if the colums are at a set width then you would hard code those widths in.

Comment: If I give input "No Name" then result could be show "MS Norway" row only. But it also shows "Datas are inside csv and Thanks" with addition of MS Norway

Comment: Unfortunately because of the design of the file this cannot be helped. Placing another ================ line before the When parsing through

Comment: Unfortunately because of the design of the file this cannot be helped. Placing another ================ line after a blank line and before the text at the end would correct this.
The other option is when parsing through the string[] if you detect a line that doesn't meet specs (does not contain the same number of tabs as the first line) then you could discard it and any remaining lines as well.

Comment: Could you please edit the code with respect to my case?

Comment: The layout of the file posted above does not show whether it uses TABs as a separator or just spaces.  Also, I assume due to font used to originally display the selection, the alignment of the columns is not intact. If the data on each line is separated by TAB characters then this is easily done in the string[] -> .csv function. Otherwise you would need to determine column widths

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126695/discussion-between-mahen-dran-and-troy-mac1ure).